# How to solve this and what is this number called?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is the real number called to which the sequence $$\gamma_n =1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n} - \log _e n$$ converges and what is the radius of convergence?

Comment: The [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Radius of convergence is irrelevant here, since it is not a power series.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $\gamma \approx 0.5772 \ldots$

Comment: Can't believe such an answer scored 20 pts.

Comment: In addition to this answer, it is not know whether or not $\gamma$ can be expressed as a rational number.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n) = \gamma$$
It is widely known as the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) which is defined as the limiting difference between the harmonic series and the natural logarithm.

$$\gamma \approx 0.5772\space1566\space4901\space5328\space6060\space6512\space090(1)$$

---

The radius of curvature is not valid for this series as it not a power-series.